# Replace downvotes with flags - or de-anonymize votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

To promote content through **upvotes, hearts or thumbs up** is a common, positive practice on many social media platforms. **Positive remarks are a very useful feature** that allows other users to quickly get to the best content available on the subject. **Flags are also important** as some content may be inappropriate for a variety of reasons - the author is notified on why the content was not appopriate, learns a lesson and moves on. That is also common practice.

**Downvotes** are typically cast on wrong answers. They are also cast on questions to punish people who did not research the issue enough before posting a question. I am questioning here whether there may be better tools that could replace downvotes. Downvotes can be replaced, or their negative effect ameliorated if:

- wrong answers would be flagged as incorrect and thus removed. There is no value in keeping wrong answers with downvotes - they add no value if not in publicly shaming users. There is also no value in humiliating a person who genuinely tried to help. Flags come with names of users, so a user feel responsible for acting respectfully.
- questions not researched enough were to be flagged as such for removal. StackExchange should build such flag. All other reasons for disapproval (duplicates, etc.) already have a corresponding flag.
- the username of the user behind the vote would be appear publicly. Anonymous downvotes are often used as "ad persona" punishment for some presumed bad intention. That behaviour is encouraged by anonymity

Bottom line: I am suggesting the abolition of downvotes and simultanous introduction of "wrong answers" and "not researched enough" flags. If that fails, I suggest attaching user names to upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174058/discussion-on-question-by-famargar-replace-downvotes-with-flags-or-de-anonymiz).

Answer (score 23):

> wrong answers can be flagged as incorrect and thus removed.

No they can't be.  Moderators cannot be the judge of whether or not an answer is incorrect, or otherwise unhelpful.  They simply do not have the domain knowledge to accurately make such judgements in all of the areas of the site, nor are there enough of them to possibly evaluate every single post that someone thinks is bad.

> There is no value in keeping wrong answers with downvotes

Many people disagree with that, but I'm not one of them.  Well, if you replace wrong with not useful anyway.  (Not all questions with incorrect statements aren't useful, and lots of things can make an answer not useful other than being wrong).

> they add no value if not in publicly shaming users.

If the author feels that the answer is no longer adding value, they can delete it.  There's no public shaming unless they refuse to do so.

> There is also no value in humiliating a person who genuinely tried to help.

The downvotes are there to be a useful signal to all readers that the post is problematic.  That is *very important information*.  Whether the author was trying to help or not is irrelevant, what matters is that the readers are given accurate information on whether or not they should trust the information in the answer as a good solution to the problem.

> Flags come with names of users, so a user feel responsible for acting respectfully.

Indicating that a solution is problematic, either due to correctness or other concerns, is not being disrespectful.

> questions not researched enough should be flagged as such for removal

This has the same problem as with answers.  Moderators are not knowledgeable enough about all fields to judge the quality of every single question, and there are not enough of them to evaluate every question people thing is bad.

> downvotes are anonymous.

Yes.

> As such, they never come with a reason for downvotes

Lots of people comment on posts to explain why they've downvoted them.  Ideally they wouldn't, and would comment with how a post can be improved instead, but many don't.

> and are thus not informative.

They're quite informative.  They're informing readers that a post is problematic and shouldn't be trusted.  That's *useful information*.  Downvotes aren't there to instruct the author on how to improve the post (that's what comments are for).  Downvotes are there to inform readers that there is a problem.  They also help inform various automated processes that a post is problematic.

Comment: I would also think it should be mentioned that answers can be downvoted for reasons other then being wrong. Such as a correct one line answer that just gives a piece of code to solve the problem with no details behind it.

Comment: @Servy thanks for answering.  I am suggesting **users** not moderators to judge on the validity of the questions/answers.

Comment: @famargar So then you prefer the current system, where regular users reflect their opinion with votes, over using flags, to indicate that a post is not useful.  The whole point of having votes is that it is precisely the way for the community to judge answers, rather than moderators.

Comment: Or use the partly broken/clogged review system ...?

Comment: Don't forget that users who think they understand the language/question/answer and vote to delete correct answers and leave incorrect/dangerous answers in place.

Comment: @Servy you have many good points. I am pleased to see that StackOverflow have found alternative ways (warning that the user is new to the site) to welcome new users and promote positive feedback